# SCLAlertView not showing

Tags: objective-c, swift, alert

I implemented the SCLAlertView in objective c. Now we porting the project to swift. I have added the SCLAlertView.h in my bridging header file. No problems with that.

I have written this code which does not have any error but it does not show the alert when I'm executing the code.

```
let alert = SCLAlertView()

alert.showError("Title", subTitle: "This is a message", closeButtonTitle: "OK", duration: 0.1)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Replace this**

```
alert.showError("Title", subTitle: "This is a message", closeButtonTitle: "OK", duration: 0.1)
```

**with**

```
alert.showSuccess(self, title: "Title", subTitle:"This is a message", closeButtonTitle: "OK", duration: 0.1)
```

Answer (score 0):

The *mystery* of why your code didn't work as it should is:

You are using the Objective c (as you mentioned) version of [SCLAlertView](https://github.com/dogo/SCLAlertView) and bridging it, which should be -as an Objective c-:

```
[alert showError:self title:@"Hello Error" subTitle:@"This is a more descriptive error text." closeButtonTitle:@"OK" duration:0.0f]; // Error
```

As you can see, the first parameter `self` refers to the current UIViewController that you want to let the alert appears in it.

So, after converting it to Swift code, it should be:

```
alert.showError(self, title: "Title", subTitle: "This is a message", closeButtonTitle: "OK", duration: 0.1)
```

What are you mentioning in the code snippet should works fine when using the Swift version of [SCLAlertView](https://github.com/vikmeup/SCLAlertView-Swift).

Note that they are different repos. If your project has been built as a "Swift" coded, I encourage to use the Swift version of SCLAlertView, you don't have to "bridge" it.

Comment: Cool. Thanks. Noted.!!

Comment: Glad to help :)

Comment: It seems that you are kind of new user of stackoverflow, I would like to note you it is good to vote up/down for questions/answers and accept them, that gives an attention to other viewers, also it helps the answerers by increasing their reputation of decreasing it if the answer was wrong. You might want to check the [Vote Up](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up) Privilege. Cheers up